React Vite Module Federation remoteEntry.js "TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module"
Host application can't access the remoteEntry.js file of the remote app.
Remote config
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'remote_app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './App': './src/App',
      },
      shared: [
        ......
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'react-query',
        'react-router-dom',
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});

Host App
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'app',
      remotes: {
        remoteApp: 'http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
    
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
})

Commands ran on both app
npm run build
npm run dev

Getting remoteEntry.js access
The issue is here is that npm run dev is the wrong command to use when running locally. To fix this, make sure you are running npm run preview on the remote app
Accessing Modules
Another issue you might run into if you are using TypeScript is loading the module. Make sure you put all modules you are declaring in a file called tsremote.d.ts the .d.ts is mandatory for this to pick up the remote modules.
Then inside the tsremote.d.ts file you can declare what you want to access
declare module 'remoteApp/App';
